# Win32 API CreateDirectory with FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE. Possible?

Tags: winapi, create-directory

I'm certainly no expert in programming on the Win32 API, but what I just learned is that using the [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function I can mark it to be deleted by the operating system once its handle is released using the `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` value. I can't seem to find a way to do the same with using the [`CreateDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363855%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or have I missed something?

Optionally, can I subscribe to changes within this specific folder (such as new files created) and then mark all files within the folder with this flag somehow?

Comment: Without having tried, I doubt Windows will honour that flag on directories. The reason being that a directory cannot be deleted if it is non-empty. How could the operating system give you a promise on deleting sometihng if it does not know if it will be able to do it.

Comment: If you expect this directory to be non-empty you have to mark all files in it for deletion no matter what (even if you use the delete flag on the directory), so FS notifications are your only option IMHO. It should also be noted that not all applications use FILE_SHARE_DELETE when opening files so you might not be able to set the delete on close flags if 3rd party applications write to this directory.

Comment: `CreateFile` isn't a method, it is a (non-member) function.  And what does `CreateDictionary` have to do with deleting files?

Answer (score 6):

You can open a handle to a directory by using the FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS flag:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    CreateDirectory(".\\testdir",NULL);
    system("pause");
    HANDLE hDir = CreateFile(".\\testdir",0,FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE|FILE_SHARE_DELETE,0,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS|FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE,NULL);
    CloseHandle(hDir);
}
```

This did work on the machine I tested on (if the directory is empty) but I'm not sure if it is documented as a valid thing to do.

Comment: The LLVM codebase has a [very similar usage](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/llvmorg-17.0.5/llvm/lib/Support/Windows/Path.inc#L276) and documents its  purpose verbosely.

Comment: FYI the directory will not get deleted if it is not empty. However in this case the API call to `CreateFile` and `CloseHandle` will both succeed and `GetLastError()` will return zero.